# Is there a way to have Bitbucket Webhooks from varying repos push JenkinsFile into a single Pipeline Project?

Tags: javascript, git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket server: server.com/projects/sites/repos/.

This directory has about 50 website front-ends, so thats 50 unique repo URLs, that I'd like Bitbucket to make a webhook call into Jenkins with. Each would have their own JenkinsFile, which i can then tell Jenkins which repo to grab the source from and which npm scripts to run.

Unfortunately, it appears I cannot for the life of me get the Bitbucket Plugin to connect to Jenkins unless I specify the EXACT repo url.. which would mean i'd have to create a Jenkins Pipeline Project for every repo.

Has anyone had any experience in keeping something similar like this DRY? If not, i'll likely avoid Jenkins and roll my own solution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten anything useful out of the bitbucket plugin for Jenkins.  I use the "Http Request Post Receive Hook", although it will only fire on pushes (apparently merging PR branches in the GUI isn't a push, so it won't fire on that event).  With the HRPRH, you can fire whatever job you want, using "buildWithParameters".

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use [Bitbucket Pull request plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.prnfs.pull-request-notifier-for-stash/server/overview) to build and deploy only merged Pull requests from your bitbucket server to Jenkins.

You can configure the Jenkins build jobs trigger in the bitbucket application and I would then do a Build on approved merged pull requests.
For pipeline jobs i found this needed to be a buildwithParamters trigger so you need to be able to trigger builds using this method.

For the Pull request notifier to trigger a Jenkins job the following needs to be configured in the bitbucket plugin settings:

```
Injection Url: http://JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=//crumb 
Injection regexp: <crumb>([^<]*)</crumb> 
Basic authentication: username and password 
URL: http://(JENKINS_URL)/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&cause=PULL_REQUEST&PULL_REQUEST_URL=${PULL_REQUEST_URL}&PULL_REQUEST_ID=${PULL_REQUEST_ID}&PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH=${PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH}&PULL_REQUEST_FROM_HASH=${PULL_REQUEST_FROM_HASH}
```

This needs to be a POST action A header needs to be added:

```
    Header: Jenkins-Crumb
    Value: ${INJECTION_URL_VALUE}
```

More detailed information can be found [here](https://dengelonsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/jenkins-pull-request-and-pipeline.html).

Comment: Appreciate the response, and read your write up. This is a terrific strategy, and something similar I use as well for my platform/service code. Unfortunately for me, we cannot have the overhead associated with a PR based workflow for our front-end projects.